# How to find an equation for a graph from a description?

Tags: functions

I've been tasked with finding a function

> $f(x)$ has a continuous second derivative and is concave up for $x < -1$ and $x > 4$ and concave down for $-1 < x < 4$.

I've drawn what I think the graph may look like but I'm wondering how I can use that to find the function, unless there is an easier way to do so?

Comment: The second derivative will have zeros where? How many such zeros? What simple function has that number of zeros? Between the zeros, you know the sign of the values of the function. That gives you more information about the desired "simple function".

Comment: Once you have a valid second derivative, just integrate twice.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let $f''(x) = a(x-r)(x-s)$. What choices for $a,r,s$ will match the specified concavity requirements for $f$?

Once you have an acceptable $f''$, just integrate twice.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y= (x+1) x (x-4),y=(x+1) (x-1.5)(x-4)$$ are possible solutions.

As an exercise find how the middle term may be modified, where the $y^{''}=0$ inflection can wander.